# How to achieve Spheres going in circle path around center

Tags: physics

I want to achieve something like on this video, where spheres/balls are going in circle motion around center.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uf6oC42U-KE on 0:16 for example.

It's not clearly visible on video, but they are like going around something in the middle.
Which physics should be used?

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Understandable, but I didn't want to cut it from video since I don't know about author rights and rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use rigid bodies:

Big sphere -> rigid body, passive, mesh

Small spheres -> rigid body, active

Animate a starting speed for the ball by keyframing start position of location, then keyframe another location at a later frame and keyframe "animated". One frame later keyframe "animated" unchecked. Blender does the rest.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Gonna try, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome